# Boot error after migrating 2nd-Gen Hyper-V hosted Gentoo Linux VM to Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, hyper-v, uefi, azure-vm

My core task is to move a small, but important, Gentoo Linux running on Hyper-V onto Azure.

Ideally, the application it's running will be migrated to a different hosting model or Linux distro that is better supported on Azure. But due to various constraints, we're hoping to have this intermediate step which will allow us to move it, as is, to Azure.

After preparing the VHD and moving the image to Azure and provisioning a VM for it, it will not boot. Through the boot diagnostics, all I see is this:
[image]

In an attempt to understand where I fail, I've tried to spin up a new local VM using the VHD prepared for Azure as the disk (Covered in (3)). When doing this, I get the same error like the one depicted above.

I'm unsure how to progress from here and would appreciate any feedback - details about how I have prepared the Gentoo VM, the VHD, and the VM on Azure follow below.

1. Basic info about the Gentoo VM

---

- It's held up to date and running 5.10.52 of the Linux kernel with Gentoo patches.
- The VM is running as a "Generation 2" VM on Hyper-V meaning, among other things, that it's UEFI based
- The VM is running off of a single disk

2. Preparing the Gentoo VM

---

In order to prepare the Gentoo image, I've mainly referred to these pieces of documentation:

- [Gentoo on Hyper-V](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hyper-V)
- [Information for Non-endorsed Distributions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-generic)

This means making sure all the Hyper-V-specific kernel requirements are met. The only thing, to my knowledge, we don't do right is run the waagent.

In order to prepare the VM for Azure, the VM is shut down. We use the Export function to export a copy of the VM to the filesystem.

3. Preparing the VHD(X)

---

From there, we convert the VHDX to a *Fixed Size* VHD, per the requirements. This is done in PowerShell through the Hyper-V CmdLets:

```
Convert-VHD -Path .\Gentoo.vhdx -DestinationPath .\Gentoo-Fixed.vhd -VHDType:Fixed
```

After this, I basically run through this script in PowerShell to:

- Create a new (Hyper-V Generation V2) Managed Disk
- Create a shared-access-signature for it
- Upload my VHD via AzCopy
- Revoke the SAS
- Create (Hyper-V Generation V2) image from the Disk

```
$azRegion  = 'northeurope'  # Geoprahical Location
$diskName  = 'gentoo-sda'   # Name of the Disk
$imageName = 'GentooAzure'
$rgName    = 'gentoo-host'  # Name of the Resource Group
$vhdSize   = (Get-Item .\Fixed-Gentoo.vhd).length

$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -SkuName:Premium_LRS -OsType:Linux -HyperVGeneration:V2 -UploadSizeInBytes:$vhdSize -Location:$azRegion -CreateOption:'Upload'
New-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName:$rgName -DiskName:$diskName -Disk:$diskConfig

$disk = Get-AzDisk -DiskName:$diskName

#At this point $disk.DiskState should return "ReadyToUpload"


# Create a writeable shared-access-signature
$diskSAS = Grant-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName:$rgName -DiskName:$diskName -DurationInSecond:86400 -Access:'Write'
$disk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName:$rgName -DiskName:$diskName

#At this point $disk.DiskState should return "ActiveUpload"

#Use AzCopy to upload the VHD
.\azcopy.exe copy ".\Fixed-Gentoo.vhd" $diskSAS.AccessSAS --blob-type PageBlob

#After the upload has been completed, revoke the SAS:
Revoke-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName:$rgName -DiskName:$diskName

#Create Image from the managed disk
$imageConfig = New-AzImageConfig -Location:$location -HyperVGeneration:V2
$imageConfig = Set-AzImageOsDisk -Image:$imageConfig -OsState:Generalized -OsType:Linux -ManagedDiskId:$disk.Id
$image = New-AzImage -ImageName:$imageName -ResourceGroupName:$rgName -Image:$imageConfig
```

4. Creating the VM

---

From this point on, I've been attempting different ways to get a VM up and running. My two main methods have been:

- Create a VM and attach the managed disk as the OS disk
- Create a VM based on the Image

Both seem to end in a non-booting machine which presents the UEFI error message posted above.

5. Debugging

---

As mentioned, in an attempt to pinpoint exactly where in my process I'm failing, I've tried to take the Fixed VHD I end up with in step (2) and mount that to a new VM on our on-prem Hyper-V. This results in the same error I see on Azure.

From this point on, I'm a but unsure about how to approach this problem. Looking at the differences between the original VM, which works, and the non-functioning created from the exported VHD this particularly catches my eye:

These are the settings listed for the **functioning Gentoo VM**:
[image]

While this is the settings from the non-functioning VM setup with the exported VHD:
[image]

It seems that some crucial boot settings are disappearing when converting the VHDX to a Fixed VHD. But at this point, I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Looking forward to your comments.

Comment: I've still not been able to resolve this. I'm currently still chasing down the root cause of the issue. I still believe, it has something to do with the VMs boot settings getting "mangled" during the export. I've concluded that it has nothing to do with the conversion from VHDX to VHD.

If I export the VM and spin up a new one using the exported VHDX as its drive, I get the same error and the "Firmware" entry, when inspecting the VM looks identical to the last screenshot in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never managed to figure out exactly **what** is happening. However, with help from the Gentoo folks on Discourse, we managed to conclude that the `/boot` partition was mangled during the transition from on-premise VM to Azure.

*(I suspect that this is what has happened every single time, no matter what transfer method I've been using.)*

I took a snapshot of the disk from the non-functional VM on Azure and mounted it to a newly created VM. From there, I mounted the `/boot` partition and concluded that the `/boot/EFI` folder only contained a single folder called `gentoo` which contained a `grubx64.efi` file.

From there, I did a `mkdir /boot/EFI/BOOT` and `cp /boot/EFI/gentoo/grubx64.efi /boot/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`.

After this, I unmounted the `/boot` partition and mounted this fixed drive back as the OS Disk of the VM.

Success. It now boots!

After logging in, I re-did the `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot` from the Gentoo Handbook.

If anyone ever manages to find any documentation on why/how the transition from on-premise to Azure mangles the boot partition, do let me know. Nevertheless, the above seems to fix it.